# Show all post of taxonomy on base taxonomy URL

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I know there have been similar answers but I'm not having any luck.

I have a custom taxonomy called events. I would like to see all the post from all terms here: domain.com/events/

That doesn't work though it gets a 404. This works though domain.com/events/term

How do I get it to work with the other way also?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redid this.  It should now work for any and all post_types:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'setup_events_rewrite');
//Gives you a new query var and sets up a rewrite rule that makes events/ work
function setup_events_rewrite() {
    //create a query var
    add_rewrite_tag('%tax_archive%','([^/]+)');
    //set new query vart with tax of choiice
    add_rewrite_rule( 'events/?$', 'index.php?tax_archive=events', 'top' );  
}

add_filter('request', 'setup_events_request');
//sets the post_type is tax_archive is set to events
function setup_events_request($qv) {
    if(isset($qv['tax_archive']) && $qv['tax_archive'] == 'events') {
        $qv['post_type'] = 'any';   //set post type to whatever you like here
    }

    return $qv;
}

add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'setup_events_post_clause', 10, 2 );
//If the query var tax_archive is set and is equal to events, it'll change the query to pull only posts that have a term from the events taxonomy
function setup_events_post_clause($clauses, $wp_query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($wp_query->query['tax_archive']) && 'events' == $wp_query->query['tax_archive']) {
        $clauses['join'].= <<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
SQL;

        $clauses['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND taxonomy = %s", $wp_query->query['tax_archive']);
        $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";      
    }

    return $clauses;
}
?>
```

Comment: I was hoping that it would work but it's just showing everything I have for index. If I do &events=term+term that works. Is there a way to output all the terms of a taxonomy with the divider being a "+"? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kel: new solution added.  This one should work.

Comment: that works if I change the post_type=post to the post type I'm using. The issue I will run into is that taxonomy can be used on different post types. Is there a way to include all post types or to specify the post types I want to use? Thanks again.

Comment: @kel: Got it working for any post type.  Change the post type in the setup_events_request function either by changing it to one or creating an array (array('post', 'page', 'whatever'))

Comment: I don't know why I'm not getting this I change `$qv['post_type'] = 'any';` to `entertainment` it's not working. Bu in the URL if I go to `?tax_archive=events&post_type=entertainment` it works just fine.